# How to get bootstrap col appear side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am usually able to do this. But for some reason everything I've tried just isn't working.

I've tried

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
        <button>Toronto</button>
        <button>Markham</button>
        <button>Petawawa</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>date</p>
        <p>date</p>
        <p>date</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And similar variations, but I can't seem to get the date and the event location to line up.

The code where the issue is occuring:

```
<div id="Location">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 aboutCopyContainer">
        <p class="copyHeader" style="font-family: testFont;">Locations</p>
        <p class="faqContent">Fall for the FEAST at an event near you!</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="btnLocationCont">

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg locationBtn locationButtonText" style="font-family: AvenirNextLTPro-Condensed;" onclick="window.location.href='http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageNavigator/UFE_ON_Oktoberfeast_Toronto.html'">Toronto</button>


          <div class="locationDateCont">
                      <p class="locatDay eventTimeBut">14</p>
                      <hr style="margin:0px;" />
                      <p class="locatMonth eventTimeBut">Oct</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">

             <div class="btnLocationCont">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg locationBtn locationButtonText" style="font-family: AvenirNextLTPro-Condensed;" onclick="window.location.href='http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageNavigator/UFE_ON_Oktoberfeast_Petawawa.html'">Petawawa</button>
            <div class="locationDateCont">
            <p class="locatDay eventTimeBut">7</p>
            <hr style="margin:0px;"/>
            <p class="locatMonth eventTimeBut">Oct</p>
            </div>
           </div> 

      <div class="btnLocationCont">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg locationBtn locationButtonText" style="font-family: AvenirNextLTPro-Condensed;" onclick="window.location.href='http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageNavigator/UFE_ON_Oktoberfeast_Markham.html'">Markham</button>
            <div class="locationDateCont">
            <p class="locatDay eventTimeBut">22</p>
            <hr style="margin:0px;"/>
            <p class="locatMonth eventTimeBut">Oct</p>
            </div>
            </div>



         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle of what's happening:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t5mjhf8/2/)

and this is the website (under Locations section) to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do (css styling etc applied).

[Oktoberfeast Locations](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageNavigator/UFE_ON_Oktoberfeast_2016_homepage.html#Location)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! thank you for your time

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle is quite different from what you've posted in your question. Please post a [mcve] here.

Comment: looks like you added `padding: 40px;` to teh class `aboutCopyContainer` so the extra padding makes the `cols` from bootstrap be wider than it can fit into one row.  Either remove the padding or make one of the columns smaller (to add up to 11)

Comment: instead of "md" try "xs". eg: use col-xs-4 instead of col-md-4

Comment: @j08691 sorry I figured it would be cleaner if I just left it in the JSFiddle, i added the part of the code that where the problem is to the question as well

Comment: @ochi that's a good idea I will try that

Comment: @varunraja I tried with the xs, what ends up happening is the locations are all in one line and then the dates are in one line below it and then its confusing to read.

Comment: @Umeed, remove fixed width from .btnLocationCont, this is the reason why the date is going under.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi that was it! since I need it for the other pages, i'll use javascript to remove it from this page. Thank you! Can you post as answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added fixed `width` inside bootstrap column child. And that width together with other element width exeeded bootsrap column width, so the class `locationDateCont` appeared underneath:

So, in your `CSS` file, remove that width from that class, and add this:

```
.btnLocationCont {
 width: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to help you! All the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this that way. Reason being is on mobile devices they won't match up.

To keep them together and display on desktop and mobile you could do something like this:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <button>Toronto</button>
        <p>date</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <button>Markham</button>
        <p>date</p>
   </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button>Petawawa</button>
        <p>date</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8t5mjhf8/4/

EDIT: To make sure the p's stay next to the buttons you need the following CSS. You will want to assign a class to the p's as to no interfere with other paragraphs.

```
p {
display: inline; 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I've tried it this way as well what ends up happening is the locations end up going in a single row and the dates appear underneath. please see screenshot http://imgur.com/a/yW0H7

Comment: Yep, the trick is you need to apply the display: inline; on your p's (although you will want to assign them a class so you don't interfere with other p's). Check the fiddle's CSS that I provided, I think that's the piece you're missing. I also updated my answer to show the code.